# Prettier config for diferent type of files in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there any way to create a prettier configuration file for different file types? For example, one for .html and one for .ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Prettier supports that. Please read about glob-based configuration overrides here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides